# python session() returns 404 but requests.get returns 200

Tags: python, session

I want to establish a persistent session where I can continually make certain requests of the server.  My first step is to simply establish a persistent session, however I get a 404 status code when I use Session(), if I use the request.get() function, it works fine.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


url = "http://192.168.100.107/public/v1/state/User"

username = "admin"
password = "password"

#response = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = ("admin", "password")
response = session.get(url)

status_code = response.status_code

print(status_code)
```

Comment: You need to use the with context manager with requests session

Comment: You could test against https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass to rule out that wherever you attempt to authenticate to behaves weird (see https://httpbin.org/ for more info). If authentication fails i would expect a `401` status code.